# Indirect of interface type in Go

Tags: pointers, go

I'm trying to create a function that will create a new instance of an interface, and assign that instance to a variable that has the type of the interface. Here is a simple example program (which does not compile):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo interface {
    Foo(int) int
}

type Foo_impl struct {}

func (f *Foo_impl) Foo(x int) int {
    return x * 2
}

func main() {
    var x *Foo_impl
    constructFoo(x)

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

func constructFoo(x Foo) {
    *x = Foo_impl{} // Blows up here - invalid indirect of x (type Foo)
}
```

Is it possible via reflection to indirect an interface variable, and assign to the underlying value? If I were not using interfaces, I would do something like this,

```
func main() {
    var x int
    foo(&x)
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", x)
}

func foo(x *int) {
    *x = 4
}
```

And as expected, this will print out 4. The issue is that interface variables cannot be indirected in the normal way. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I've also tried using a `*Foo` as the parameter to `constructFoo`, but that does not work either, since `**Foo_impl` isn't a `*Foo`.

Comment: You can't pass `nil` pointers and somehow initialized them, since it's the pointer value that's nil. Like you said, you need a `**Foo_impl` if you want to initialize the pointer itself. Why is it a problem to write separate constructors? If there is no real constructor logic and it can be done in a single function, why can't you use struct literals or values like most code?

Comment: I'm trying to write a function that will initialize all of the mocks that I need for a test. I have a lot of mock structs, and I don't want to write 20 identical constructors for all of them. They all need to be initialized in exactly the same way, so I thought this would make things easier.

Comment: @NateMara you can pass an interface which will accept any struct and then get its underlying type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to write a function that did what I want

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Y interface {
    SetX(int)
}

type X struct {
    test int
}

func (x *X) SetX(param int) {
    x.test = param
}

func main() {
    var x *X
    y := foo(&x)
    y.SetX(12)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", x)
}

func foo(x interface{}) Y {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(x)
    pointerType := t.Elem()
    realType := pointerType.Elem()

    pointer := reflect.New(realType)
    reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(x)).Set(pointer)

    return pointer.Interface().(Y)
}
```

The `foo` function can initialize any double pointer to a type that implements `Y`, and it returns the new instance as a `Y`.

Answer (score 4):

But why can't you be more idiomatic and do

```
func constructFoo() Foo {
    return &Foo_impl{} 
}
```

then, in main:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(constructFoo().Foo(10))
}
```

?

Also, there is [accept interfaces, return structs](https://medium.com/@cep21/what-accept-interfaces-return-structs-means-in-go-2fe879e25ee8) approach which may be interesting for you.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: In reality, I'm trying to create a varadic function that accepts multiple nil pointers to `Foo`s of different concrete types (around 20 different types), and initialize all of them. So I'm doing this to try and avoid writing the 20 separate constructors that would be required.

Comment: Looks like it's faster to just write them ;)) Go ain't no Lisp

Comment: I was able to make a function that did what I wanted. It's not pretty, but it works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049680/3204951

Comment: Good for you, although I would raise an ideological argument that using `reflect` for your case is an overkill (and a runtime perf penalty), as I said Go is not self-reflecting-self-modifying Lisp and really the Go way is to simply write 20 constructors, or if you have 120 - just generate them, not necessarily by `go generate`, maybe by shell/awk/Python oneliner.
I am sure Go creators, esp. Ken, would agree with me. :]

Answer (score 1):

Implementing an interface will help you to pass mock structs to your function and then using type assertion you can get the value of struct. Basically interface is the only way in which you can wrap your any type and pass it to the function and then using type assertions you can get the underlying value.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Foo interface {
    Foo(int) int
}

type Foo_impl struct {}

func (f *Foo_impl) Foo(x int) int {
    return x * 2
}

func main() {
    var x *Foo_impl
    constructFoo(x)
}

func constructFoo(x interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(x.(interface{}).(*Foo_impl).Foo(10)) // dereference the type to call the function  on pointer receiver
}
```

Also It is required to dereference the value of type struct passed to the constructor to call the method using pointer receiver.

Check working code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MpfEGzJHCy_N)

In Golang [Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) is defined as:

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>
> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the
>   dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must
>   implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is
>   invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If
>   T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x
>   implements the interface T.

Answer (score 0):

In Go, if we have a type

```
type Foo_impl struct {}
```

We usually using

```
func NewFoo_impl() *Foo_impl
```

to create this instance of this structure(if need)

There is no instance of the interface, we just say a type implement an interface or not.

So your code can be

```
var x Foo
x = NewFoo_impl()
// or x = &Foo_impl{}
```

About indirect the interface type, it's not hard to understand by knowing it just like `void*` in C.

Dereference it won't return the type you want, in fact, the compiler also doesn't know how to deal with it. It became an incomplete type, so Go's decision is disallowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your requirements, however a pointer of the type that is being passed to you constructor method can not be nil, one way to address it is to use default instance.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)


var defaultFooImpl = &Foo_impl{}

type Foo interface {
    Foo(int) int
}

type Foo_impl struct {
    id int
}

func (f *Foo_impl) Foo(x int) int {
    return x * 2
}



func main() {
    var x *Foo_impl = defaultFooImpl
    constructFoo(x)

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground %v", x)
}

func constructFoo(x Foo) {
    switch value :=x.(type) {
        case *Foo_impl:
            *value = Foo_impl{2}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach with varadic function that accepts multiple nil pointers to Foo,

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

type Foo interface {
    Foo(int) int
}

type Foo_impl struct {
    id int
}

func (f *Foo_impl) Foo(x int) int {
    return x * 2
}



func main() {
    var x *Foo_impl
    var x1 = []Foo{x}
    constructFoo(x1...)


    fmt.Println("Hello, playground %v", x1[0])
}

func constructFoo(x ...Foo) {
    for i, foo := range x {
        switch  (foo).(type) {
            case *Foo_impl:
                x[i] = &Foo_impl{2}
        }
    }

}
```